Однокоренные слова в Python
Мне нужно получать однокоренные слова с указанием части речи. Как я понимаю, для английского языка такое решение есть. Но для русского не нашла ничего подходящего
Например:
энергетический + сущ -> энергетика
московский + сущ -> москва
молодежь + прил -> молодежный

Мне это нужно для улучшения качества поисковой системы по документам 1с, которые я передаю в opensearch в виде json-ов.



Правильное наименование
Для него запрос пользователя




"департамент образования города москвы "
"московский департамент образования"


"департамент финансов"
"финансовый департамент"


"агентство энергетической эффективности мурманской области"
"агентство энергетики мурманск"



Pymorphy2, как я понимаю, нормализует только до той же части речи
Использование нечеткого (fuzzy) поиска мне не очень нравится, хотелось бы иметь возможность именно переходить от одной части речи к другой с тем же корнем

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.
